# The mappings Entity and another Entity are inconsistent with each other

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with my relations between my entities.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class StatusUpdate
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Manager", inversedBy="statusUpdates", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private ?Manager $manager;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Order", inversedBy="statusUpdates", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private ?Order $order;
}
```

My second entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Manager extends User
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\StatusUpdate", mappedBy="manager", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected Collection $statusUpdates;
...
}
```

My third entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Order extends AbstractEntity
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\StatusUpdate", mappedBy="order", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected Collection $statusUpdates;
...
}
```

It gives me a mapping error:

> [FAIL] The entity-class AppBundle\Entity\StatusUpdate mapping is invalid:

- The mappings AppBundle\Entity\StatusUpdate#manager and AppBundle\Entity\Manager#statusUpdates are inconsistent with each other.

if you comment on the manager property in the StatusUpdate class, the error disappears

Comment: 'order' is a reserved word so using it as a property name is a bit problematical.  This does not explain why commenting out the manager property appeared to have fixed things.  I made a quick test using attributes and things seemed to work as expected.  It is possible that the problem might be in one of your base classes.

Comment: thanks, I realized that there were problems with the name, I fixed it by renaming